# How can I eliminate #error on SSRS expression when dividing by zero?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am trying to eliminate #error when dividing by zero on my SSRS report. I have the following expression which still gives #error

```
=IIf(IsNothing(Lookup(Fields!id.Value, Fields!id2.Value, Fields!Stock.Value, "Models")),
88 , Fields!QTY_AVL.Value * 100 / 
Lookup(Fields!id.Value, Fields!id2.Value, Fields!Stock.Value, "Models"))
```

However if switch the / to * , as below, I correctly get the value 88

```
=IIf(IsNothing(Lookup(Fields!id.Value, Fields!id2.Value, Fields!Stock.Value, "Models")), 
88 , Fields!QTY_AVL.Value * 100 * 
Lookup(Fields!id.Value, Fields!id2.Value, Fields!Stock.Value, "Models"))
```

In both instances I get the correct value is the lookup value > 0

```
(Fields!QTY_AVL and Fields!Stock come from different sources)
```

Am I missing something obvious? Any insight into this much appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

You can add a safe divide function if you go to Report Properties and then click Code, then reference this in your expression as `CODE.SafeDivide(Value1, Value2)`, adding the parameters as necessary.

This function will return 0 instead of displaying the #error message.

```
Public Function SafeDivide(ByVal Numerator As Decimal, ByVal Denominator As Decimal) As Decimal
    If Denominator = 0 Then
        Return 0
    End If
    Return (Numerator / Denominator)
End Function
```