# SSRS expression causing error

Tags: sql, regex, reporting-services

I have the following expression in SSRS:-

```
=IIf(IsNothing(Fields!Hours.Value), 0, Sum(Fields!Hours.Value) / Sum(Fields!ReportingHours.Value))
```

The expression appears as `#Error`.  I removed the division part of the equation, leaving just this:

```
=IIf(IsNothing(Fields!Hours.Value), 0, Sum(Fields!Hours.Value))
```

Then the correct numbers appear.  If I perform an addition operation, the calculation also errors out.  It seems that it does not like something about performing mathematical operations when using the `Sum()` function.  If I do simple division without the Sum, as in this expression:

```
=IIf(IsNothing(Fields!Hours.Value), 0, Fields!Hours.Value / Fields!ReportingHours.Value)
```

Then numbers show up fine.  It is only when I have the `Sum()` function on the expression that causes an error.  Any ideas as to how to fix this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13345926/how-can-i-eliminate-error-on-ssrs-expression-when-dividing-by-zero or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189132/ssrs-expression-divide-by-zero-error for various workarounds

Comment: Indeed. There's no short-circuit evaluation on `IIf` in VBScript. How you deal with it will depend on your data and what you want to happen when `Sum(Fields!ReportingHours.Value)` may be zero or Nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following expression:-

```
=IIf(IsNothing(sum(Fields!Hours.Value)), 0, Sum(Fields!Hours.Value) / Sum(Fields!ReportingHours.Value)
```

**EDIT**

I have edited my previous post.

Comment: The proposed solution did not work.  It seems that any expression that contains two fields with the SUM() function returns an error.  If I only use SUM() on one field, it works.  I can't figure out how to fix it.

Comment: @user3465260 I have edited my previous post. please check and comment.