# how to avoid #Error and NaN in SSRS

Tags: vb.net, t-sql, reporting-services

I have this expression in my report in order to calculate ratios:

```
=
SUM(Fields!PaidLosses.Value) / 
Lookup(Fields!YearNum.Value & Fields!MonthNum.Value, Fields!YearStartRisk.Value & Fields!MonthNum.Value, Fields!EarnedPremium.Value, "EarnedAllCoverages")
```

When I am choosing a parameter with not enough data I got #Error and NaN. 
The result of NaN is the division of "-" on "-" values. And the result of #Error is the division of "-" on 0 values. 
[image]

Comment: Have you tried using IIF to bypass invalid values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
=SUM(Fields!PaidLosses.Value) / 
IIF(
ISNOTHING(
  Lookup(Fields!YearNum.Value & Fields!MonthNum.Value,
  Fields!YearStartRisk.Value & Fields!MonthNum.Value,
  Fields!EarnedPremium.Value, "EarnedAllCoverages")
) OR 
Lookup(Fields!YearNum.Value & Fields!MonthNum.Value,
Fields!YearStartRisk.Value & Fields!MonthNum.Value,
Fields!EarnedPremium.Value, "EarnedAllCoverages") = 0,1,
Lookup(Fields!YearNum.Value & Fields!MonthNum.Value,
Fields!YearStartRisk.Value & Fields!MonthNum.Value,
Fields!EarnedPremium.Value, "EarnedAllCoverages")
)
```

This is caused because you cannot divide any number by zero or `nothing` (SSRS nulls)

Also you can use this custom code provided in [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13346456/2647648) to safely perform divisions.

Add the below code in the custom code textarea in `Report` menu / `Report Properties...` / `Code` tab

```
Public Function SafeDivide(ByVal Numerator As Decimal, ByVal Denominator As Decimal) As Decimal
    If Denominator = 0 Then
        Return 0
    End If
    Return (Numerator / Denominator)
End Function
```

Then in your tablix just call the function with the numerator and denominator as arguments:

```
=Code.SafeDivide(
  SUM(Fields!PaidLosses.Value),
  Lookup(
    Fields!YearNum.Value & Fields!MonthNum.Value,
    Fields!YearStartRisk.Value & Fields!MonthNum.Value,
    Fields!EarnedPremium.Value, "EarnedAllCoverages"
    )
  )
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Custom code doing exactly what I need!! Thank you very much Alejandro!!!