# SSRS Division issue in column grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, business-intelligence

Problem: Having trouble getting an accurate division on a "sub-matrix" when using drill down, works on totals but not detail level.

Report:

[image: Report]

Visual Studio Design of the report:
[image]

Now the current SSRS expression I'm using in the "% Of total" section is:

=Code.SafeDivide(Fields!Orders.Value , Sum(Fields!Orders.Value))

and the embedded code was a recommendation from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13345926/how-can-i-eliminate-error-on-ssrs-expression-when-dividing-by-zero):

```
Public Function SafeDivide(ByVal Numerator As Decimal, ByVal Denominator As Decimal) As Decimal
If Denominator = 0 Then
    Return 0
End If
Return (Numerator / Denominator)
End Function
```

Data results looks like:

[image]

Now if you look at the first picture and calculate the divison of the highlighted values, i would expect the outcome to be 72% not 6%.

Any ideas? Maybe i've tried a few things but seem like im chasing my tail, would of though this would be simply straight forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to pass in a sum rather than a single order amount, and then tell your existing sum function the overall group to sum e.g. I think your expression should probably be something like this:

```
=Code.SafeDivide(Sum(Fields!Orders.Value), Sum(Fields!Orders.Value, 'Overall Group Name'))
```

Comment: Thanks this did the job, knew I just had to sleep on it!